# Java - not adding to ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

My code is not adding a new index to an `ArrayList` of `object[]`'s.

My code:

```
            System.out.println("started1");
            ArrayList<Object[]> toSend = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
            System.out.println("started2");
            for(Entry<String, Room> map : rooms.entrySet())
            {
                System.out.println("started3");
                String key = map.getKey();
                Room val = map.getValue();
                System.out.println("started3.1");
                Player owner = players.get(val.getOwnerID());
                System.out.println("started3.125");
                Object[] toAdd = new Object[] {key, val.getRoomName(), val.getCurrentPlayerSize(), val.getMaxPlayers(), owner.getName()};

                System.out.println("started3.15");
                toSend.add(toAdd);
                System.out.println("started3.2");
            }

            System.out.println("started4");
            client.sendEvent("refreshAvailableRooms", toSend);
            System.out.println("started5");
```

It gets as far as setting the `owner` variable to link to a `Player` class. I have tried printing out the class values and they are all fine.  It just stops when I try adding a new `Object[]` to my array of objects.

What could be going wrong? (In the console it stops printing after `System.out.println(started3.125");`

EDIT: I should mention that `rooms` (in the for loop) link to a HashMap:

```
private static HashMap<String, Player> players = new HashMap<String, Player>();
private static HashMap<String, Room> rooms = new HashMap<String, Room>();
```

EDIT2:  RUNNABLE CODE

```
Room.java:

public class Room {
   public String RoomName = "Room Name";
   public int size = 3;
   public int max = 10;
   public String ownerID = "BobSmith";
   public String ID = "Room1";

   public Room() { }
}

Player.java:
public class Player {
   public String ID = "BobSmith";
   public String Name = "Bob";
   public Player() { }
}

Main.java:
public class main {
   private static HashMap<String, Player> players = new HashMap<String, Player>();
   private static HashMap<String, Room> rooms = new HashMap<String, Room>();
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      players.put("BobSmith", new Player());
      rooms.put("Room1", new Room());
      rooms.put("Room2", new Room());
      rooms.put("Room3", new Room());

            System.out.println("started1");
            ArrayList<Object[]> toSend = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
            System.out.println("started2");
            for(Entry<String, Room> map : rooms.entrySet())
            {
                System.out.println("started3");
                String key = map.getKey();
                Room val = map.getValue();
                System.out.println("started3.1");
                Player owner = players.get(val.ownerID);
                System.out.println("started3.125");
                Object[] toAdd = new Object[] {key, val.RoomName, val.size, val.max, owner.Name};

                System.out.println("started3.15");
                toSend.add(toAdd);
                System.out.println("started3.2");
            }

            System.out.println("started4");
   }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: does it print an error when it stops?

Comment: is `System.out.println(started3.125");` a copy paste error or compile error?

Comment: @Danny It does not print any error. The rest of the program keeps working, however in this specific function it stops at that point and doesn't do anything else below it.

Comment: @user2341963 copy paste error. my bad! Fixed.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Sorry! I will see what I can do now.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added some runnable code. Hopefully it works.

Comment: @zuc0001, did you tried to debug code line by line? And what you meant under "it stops at that point and doesn't do anything else below it"? Did if throws error, but you added somewhere upper the call stack the `try {} catch(e) {}` with silently swollen exception?

Comment: @zuc0001, example code runs without problems, so there can be not many of possibilities: if on `new Object[]{...}` execution hangs - then you have some hang-able code in those getters `val.getRoomName(), val.getCurrentPlayerSize(), val.getMaxPlayers(), owner.getName()`, if not - then one of that getters throws error, but you catch'ed it somewhere and forgot to `ex.printStackTrace()` or rethrow it.

Comment: @ankhzet That's odd. I've done absolutely no exception handling within the program yet. I'll try print out each of the val.() parts because I've only tried a few.  Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @ankhzet Found the problem! I had set up the `player` incorrectly, so it was linking to a HashMap that didn't exist!

Comment: I still wondering, why you using output to console instead of line-by-line execution with debugger? Or you don't using IDE, and actually compiling from console? o_O

Comment: @ankhzet I've never used a Java debugger. I'm quite new to it.

Comment: I don't know about Java debuggers either. I talked about debugger, integrated into IDE, like [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org) (which i'm using)